# how to make this code works if i used it inside update panel and some of the checkbox values will be disabled according to database field ..?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This code works fine if i use this inside ssercontrol > panel and i have a checkboxes in table when no checkbox is checked its works fine .... but if i disabled and checked any of the textbox then this doesn't work .... in usercontrol why ? i didnt understand ..

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkboxChecked(){
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i=0; i<allInputs.length; i++) {
         var chk = allInputs[i];
         if(chk.type == "checkbox" && !chk.disabled && chk.checked) {

            return true;
         } 
    }
 alert("OOps! You haven't selected all available checkboxes");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check single by single then use

> $("#isSelected ").checked == true

for all use

> $('input[name *=
>   isSelected]').attr('checked', true);

html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="isSelected"/>
```

Comment: i think you didnt understand my question ..n try to reedit my this code. .. i want a small fix in that...thid code is working fine but i want if i have already checked and disable both the property in same checkbox then this will not display msgbox

Comment: i have some checkboxes which have both property checked and disabled both ... due to this property this code fails to respond ... and msgbox will not display

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand completly. Need you to alert when one checkbox isn't checked?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkboxChecked(){
    var checked=true;
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var i=0;
    while(checked && i<allInputs.length){
         var chk=allInputs[i];
         if(chk.type == "checkbox"){
            if(!chk.disabled && !chk.checked){
               checked=false;// With one not checked is suficient
            }
         }
         i++;
    }
    if(!checked)
        alert("OOps! You haven't select checkboxes");
    return checked;
}
</script>
```

Comment: assume that i have three checkboxes in webpage ... out of 3 1 checkboxes is already disabled and checked  ...then if user forgot to check any of the checkbox then msg box will appear you havent select checkbox if user select one or all checkbox out of remaining checkboxes the user will be redirected to next page

Comment: means user have to check atleast one check box to go to the next page on button click,it is not necessary for user to check all checkboxes to proceed to next page

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. It will pop an alert box if any of the enabled checkboxes have not been checked when this function is run. It also returns true or false if you need that for some reason.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkboxChecked(){
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i=0; i<allInputs.length; i++) {
         var chk = allInputs[i];
         if(chk.type == "checkbox" && !chk.disabled && !chk.checked) {
            alert("OOps! You haven't selected all available checkboxes");
            return false;
         } 
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: assume that i have three checkboxes in webpage ... out of 3 1 checkboxes is already disabled and checked ...then if user forgot to check any of the checkbox then msg box will appear you havent select checkbox if user select one or all checkbox out of remaining checkboxes the user will be redirected to next page

Comment: means user have to check atleast one check box to go to the next page on button click,it is not necessary for user to check all checkboxes to proceed to next page

Comment: I'm glad you found the correct solution. For future questions, more clarity around what exactly you're trying to do will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**THE CORRECT ANSWER IS THIS :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkboxChecked(){
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i=0; i<allInputs.length; i++) {
         var chk = allInputs[i];
         if(chk.type == "checkbox" && !chk.disabled && chk.checked) {

            return true;
         } 
    }
 alert("OOps! You haven't selected all available checkboxes");
    return false;
}
</script>
```